# Twilio: No such module `Alarmofire` when trying to get started

Tags: swift, xcode, twilio

Im trying to learn the ropes of Twilio. The goal is to send text messages from my app. Im following [this getting started guide](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/sending-text-messages-in-swift-with-twilio.html)

At the last step is to run this command in terminal: (yes I have changed `SwiftSMS`with my own project name)

```
swift build && ./.build/debug/SwiftSMS
```

This command results in the following:

> MyMac:MyProject MyName$ swift build && ./.build/debug/myProject Compile
>   Swift Module 'myProject' (1 sources)
>   /Volumes/myProject/myProject/Sources/myProject/main.swift:2:8: error:
>   no such module 'Alamofire'
>   import Alamofire
>
> ^     error: terminated(1): /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build-tool
>   -f /Volumes/myProject/myProject/.build/debug.yaml main output:

I have not done any config with Twilio in Xcode yet. As far as I can understand from the guide should this send a message without doing anything in Xcode?

**EDIT***:
Package.swift:

```
    // swift-tools-version:4.2
    // The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

 import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "myProject",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "myProject",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "myProjectTests",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
        ]
)
```

Comment: Apparently, the `Alamofire` framework wasn't added to your project. Check your `Package.swift`

Comment: @Gereon I have made some changes to the Package.swift. Now the error code is: `/Volumes/myProject/myProject: error: manifest parse error(s):
/Volumes/myProject/myProject/Package.swift:8:20: error: cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected element type 'Package.Dependency'
    dependencies: ["Alamofire"]`,  I have added the `Package.swift to the original question

Comment: This error suggests that you haven't used the correct syntax for your `Package.swift`. Did you only add a string value of the dependency name rather than defining an actual package using `.package(...)`?

Comment: @JamieEdge You where off course  right. I edited the `Package.swift to accommodate the guide. Now the build runs without errors, but according to the guide I should have received a text message on my personal telephone number. But I did not receive anything. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Use this as your `Package.swift` - you can't simply say "Alamofire" and expect SPM to magically know where to get the sources from.

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "myProject",
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "myProject",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "myProject Tests",
            dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
        ]
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Thought I had updated my original question. I have updated the  `Package.swift` and now it runs without any errors, but according to the guide I should have received a text message, but I did not. any suggestions?

Comment: Are you using the correct Twilio phone number? Is your code let parameters = `["From": "YOUR_TWILIO_NUMBER", "To": "YOUR_PERSONAL_NUMBER", "Body": "Hello from Swift!"]`?

Comment: @lizziepika Yes, I have the correct numbers: ` let parameters = ["From": "myTwilioNumber", "To": "myPrivateNumber", "Body": "Hello from Swift!"]` Note; I have a trial number from Twilio, but that should not be the issue?

Comment: More importantly, you should ask this as a new separate question.