# Twilio: Not sending text message when following get started guide

Tags: swift, twilio

As a continuation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54079000/twilio-no-such-module-alarmofire-when-trying-to-get-started/54081066#54081066) I'm not receiving any text message after following [this guide](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/sending-text-messages-in-swift-with-twilio.html). I am also not getting any errors.

**This is my `Package.swift` file:**

```
    import PackageDescription

    let package = Package(
        name: "MyProject",
        dependencies: [
            .package(url: "https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git", from: "4.0.0")
        ],
        targets: [
            .target(
                name: "MyProject",
                dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
            .testTarget(
                name: "MyProjectTests",
                dependencies: ["Alamofire"]),
            ]
    )
```

**This is my `main.swift´file`:**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_PERSONAL_SID"],
    let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_PERSONAL_AUTHTOKEN"] {

    let url = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/\(accountSID)/Messages"
    let parameters = ["From": "MY_TWILIONUMBER", "To": "MY_PERSONAL_NUMBER", "Body": "Hello from Swift!"]

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
        .authenticate(user: accountSID, password: authToken)
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }

    RunLoop.main.run()
}
```

When I run `swift build && ./.build/debug/MyProject` it seemingly works fine, but I'm not receiving any message.

I´m not sure what I have done wrong, but I have some questions:

1. These two commands:

   `export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID='YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID'`
    `export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN='YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'`
   Can I run them in terminal from where ever? Or should they be ran in a specific folder? (I changed the `SID` and `TOKEN` to my personal ones when I ran the commands)
2. The `Package.swift` should be located in the base folder of my Xcode project?
3. The `main.swift`should be located in `.../MyProject/Sources/MyProject/main.swift`?
4. The command `swift build && ./.build/debug/MyProject`
   In the guide under the explanation of ´main.swift´ it says:

> Run it with this command, and you should receive a text message!

Do they mean something special with `run it with this command`? Or can I just run the command from terminal from where ever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you run

```
export TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID='YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID'
export TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN='YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN'
```

you need to do so in the terminal in the same window that you eventually run your application from. You can read more about [setting environment variables in this blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/01/how-to-set-environment-variables.html).

In your `main.swift` file you have the line:

```
if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_PERSONAL_SID"],
    let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["MY_PERSONAL_AUTHTOKEN"] {
```

I believe that your program is running but not sending anything because you are trying to assign variables from the environment called `MY_PERSONAL_SID` and `MY_PERSONAL_AUTHTOKEN`. If you are exporting environment variables as you describe, then this line should be:

```
if let accountSID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID"],
    let authToken = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"] {
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Perfect! The error was that I had put my personal information in the `accountSID´ and `authToken` I'm getting a error at the end of the session in terminal: `[Data]: 925 bytes
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))` Is this something I need to fix?

Comment: Looks like a JSON parsing error, try adding `.json` to the end of the URL you are requesting. Are you able to print out the response before trying to parse it?